# Como apresentar o erro vindo do MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, pdo

Fiz o código abaixo, e funciona perfeitamente, porém caso o MySQL retorne algum erro, como saberei?

Não tenho ideia, alguém pode me ajudar?

A mensagem deve retornar no `alert`, porém eu consegui criar o `alert` de `Sucesso`, porém como faço o 'alert'  com retorno do erro quando 'false' ???

Segue o código:

```
var nome_arquivo_api = "clientes.php";    
var end_arquivo_api = "api/include/";
var complemento_api = "?action=";  
var lista_excluir_api = "lista_excluir";

var url_excluir_api = end_arquivo_api+nome_arquivo_api+complemento_api+lista_excluir_api;   

$scope.apagarRegistro = function (id) {
    for (i in $scope.listagem) {
        if ($scope.listagem[i].id == id) { 
            $http.post(url_excluir_api,
                    {
                        'id': id
                    }
            )
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $http.get(url_listar_api).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.listagem = data;
                    $.gritter.add({
                        title: '<div style="color:#43A608;">ATENÇÃO</div>',
                        text: 'Registro Excluído com Sucesso!',
                        image: 'assets/images/icon_sucesso.png',
                        sticky: false,
                        time: ''
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Arquivo PHP:

```
function lista_excluir() {

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$item_id = $data->id;

if (PDO_excluirRegistro("administradores", $item_id, "id")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Função PHP:

```
function PDO_excluirRegistro($tabela, $id, $campo_chave) {
$pdo = conectarBanco();
try {
    $deletar = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabela WHERE $campo_chave = ?");
    $deletar->bindValue(1, $id);
    $deletar->execute();

    if ($deletar->rowCount() == 1) :
        return true;
    else :
        return false;
    endif;
} catch (PDOException $error) {
    echo "<h4>";
    echo "Mensagem de Erro: " . $error->getMessage();
    echo "</h4>";
}}
```

Comment: Você já tentou usar o console do navegador? E incluir a tag console no seu js? console.log(var);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu códgio PHP precisa retornar um código de HTTP que não seja `200`. Simplesmente retornando `true` ou `false` não é suficiente - em ambos os casos, o `$http.post()` retorna *com successo*, mas simplesmente o *sucesso* tem o valor de `false`.

Em PHP, teria que alterar os Headers da mensagem voltando. Um código bem simples seria usando a função `header()`:

```
function lista_excluir() {

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$item_id = $data->id;

if (PDO_excluirRegistro("administradores", $item_id, "id")) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    return true; // Aqui, você devolve o valor 'true', porém poderia conter HTML ou JSON também
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    return false; // Mesmo aqui
}
}
```

#### Mais informações

Tecnologias de web (como javascript, e por conseguinte, angularJS) usa o padrão do HTTP/1.1. Esse padrão define vários códgios de retorno. Chamam *HTTP Status Codes*, ou *Códgios de status HTTP*. Existem muitos recursos para aprender mais sobre eles, um deles [sendo esse artigo do Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_status_HTTP).